# writing generated numbers to a table in assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I am generating 5 random numbers and I want to write them down to a table. At the end, in the variable `array`, I have one digit, that is, the last one that was generated. How can I make sure that they are all, the previous figure is also saved?

```
_DATA SEGMENT

    array dd 5 dup(?)

_DATA ENDS

_TEXT SEGMENT
main proc

; -- generating random numbers --
    call GetTickCount
    push eax 
    call nseed

    mov ecx, 5
    generateRandomNumbers:
    push ecx

    ;--- generating random numbers from 0 to 9 ---
        push 9
        call nrandom
        mov array, eax 

    pop ecx
    loop generateRandomNumbers
; -- end -- 

    push 0
    call ExitProcess
main endp
_TEXT   ENDS
```

My output:

```
&array = 2
```

I would like to receive

```
&array = 5, 1, 7, 6, 4
```

Comment: Since they are random you probably don't care about order. So you might as well store them in reverse. `mov [array+4*ecx-4], eax`. Do this after the `pop ecx` since you need that for indexing.

Comment: If you had `mov [array], eax` that would be doing `array[0] = eax;`, so same location every time.  Some variable indexing is needed to store to different array elements.  `array[i] = eax` for example.   Jester's comment is to combine the count down counter with indexing so you don't have to introduce another variable for counting up, but that is another option.  Also instead of count up index, could use an advancing pointer instead, so like `*ptr = eax; ptr++`.

Comment: @Jester Why if I want to add 20 numbers to the table and write `mov [array+19*ecx-19], eax`, then it gives an error?

Comment: @np.  You changed two different 4's into 19.  Just put them back to 4's.  The first 4 is the scaling factor, which is still 4 b/c it is still an array of 4 byte values.  The second 4 is to go back one element, since the counter in `ecx` holds 1 more than the backwards index to use at that iteration.  So, when `ecx` is 3, for example, you want to store in array[2], which is 4 bytes earlier in memory than array[3], or (e.g. store to array[ecx-1].)  When the `ecx` is 20, you want to store into array[ecx-1], e.g. array[19], so that is still the same store Jester wrote.

Comment: The indexing would change when changing the size of the elements of the array, or if you were to change from counting down to counting up.  However, the indexing doesn't change when increasing the number of elements in the array.  For that, just increasing the loop iteration count is sufficient.